# Finding analytic functions that satisfy a condition.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Find all of the analytic functions $f(z)$ on the closed unit disc $|z|≤1$ which satisfy the condition $\text{Re}[f(z)]=1$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ on the unit circle $|z|=1$.

I thought maybe I could use the lemma:
$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int u(x+r\cos t,y+r\sin t)dt$$
when $u(x,y)$ is the real part of $f(x,y)$, but I don't know how to go on from here.

Comment: use compactness and open mapping theorem to conclude that the maximum and minimum real value of $f\big(\overline D\big)$ is $1$.  Apply open mapping theorem once more to conclude $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: such a function must be constant. Indeed, look at $e^f$, which is of constant module $e$ over the unit circle. Then, it must follow that it is a finite Blaschke product. However, it cannot have any zeroes, because $\exp$ never vanishes. Thus, $e^f$ must be the empty Blaschke product ie a constant map, which implies that $f$ is also constant.